# Optimal Way To Differentiate Between Exactly Two Elements with CSS

Tags: html, css

Let's say I know that there will be exactly two (no more, no less) of a given HTML  element. What is the optimal, cleanest way to differentiate between these two elements in CSS?

I know you could just given them different IDs: for example,

```
<section id="1"> Hello </section>
<section id="2"> World </section>

#1 {
    color: red;
}
#2 {
    color: blue;
}
```

But it seems cleaner to not use those unnecessary id-tags. So the cleanest I've gotten it is:

```
<section> Hello </section>
<section> World </section>

section:nth-of-type(1) {
    color: red;
}
section:nth-of-type(2) {
    color: blue;
}
```

But there are other things such as `first-of-type` (though no `second-of-type`) that I've found.

Is my second example the cleanest, most CSS-y way to do it? Is there a better way?

Comment: Classes is the recommended way

Comment: @LGSon when they're unique, IDs are the recommended way, being that IDs are unique. Classes are for when you need to apply the same to multiple elements.

Comment: @Adrian I was too general...yes, you are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I've seen (even though it makes the code longer) the first way is the best way to approach it in the long run, even though for the time being both ways work perfectly fine. The code is short enough as it is so the extra id attributes shouldn't be too long, and if you decide to change your page with more sections down the road, you will have a lot less editing to do within your css to maintain your existing sections.

EDIT: I should say that classes tend to be more widely accepted than ids, but both will do the trick for you. Classes would make it easier for you to style sections exactly the same way you would style these sections down the road, if you would like to do that.